# Iterating through hashmap - exception being thrown

Tags: java, hashmap

This is related to a question I asked earlier:
[Iterating through hashmap and creating unique objects - trying to prevent duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13896528/1005450)

And while I assumed I could apply a similar logic for my remove method that I had for my add method, the exception I have to check for a non existent record is getting thrown even though I know very well the record exists and should be removed. My delete method is as follows:

```
    public boolean removePatron(int libraryCardNumber) throws PatronException {
    boolean patronRemoved = false;
    int keyToRemove = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() != libraryCardNumber) {
            throw new PatronException("This record does not exist");

        }
        keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
    }
    patrons.remove(keyToRemove);
    patronRemoved = true;
    return patronRemoved;
}
```

For reference, the Patron objects look like this:

```
public class Patron {

//attributes
private String name = null;
private int cardNumber = 0;

//operations
public Patron (String name, int cardNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;

}

public int getCardNumber(){
    return cardNumber;
}

 }
```

My test simply adds three patrons first, and then tries to remove it by a card number that I know would exist. I added a println of the Patron's number in my add method so I could see them easily while messing with this in eclipse as they get added.

```
    @Test
public void testRemovePatron() {
    boolean exceptionThrown = false;
    try {
        testLibrary.addPatron("TestName");
        testLibrary.addPatron("TestName2");
        testLibrary.addPatron("TestName3");
        testLibrary.removePatron(1);
    } catch (PatronException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        exceptionThrown = true;
        fail("what the hell is going on");
    }
    assertFalse(exceptionThrown);
}
```

I get the exception from the remove method thrown every time.

Edit: I made a small change to the provided answer, to account for needing to throw an exception if there was no match found:

```
    public boolean removePatron(int libraryCardNumber) throws PatronException {
    boolean patronRemoved = false;
    int keyToRemove = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() == libraryCardNumber) 
        {
            keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
            patronRemoved = true;
        }
    }
    if (patronRemoved)
    {
        patrons.remove(keyToRemove);
    } else {
        throw new PatronException("This record did not exist");
    }
    return patronRemoved;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? what is your logic ?

Comment: I've got a map of Patron lists that I can add to, as reflected in: Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet(). I want to remove records by providing a number that will then correspond to the card number in the Patron object, which is constructed with a String name and int cardNumber. When the patrons are created the int card number is the same as the Key for the Patron in the hashmap.

Comment: @Thihara it throws throw new PatronException("This record does not exist"); No matter what card number I provide it doesn't get past this exception

Comment: What is `addPatron` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception will throw for any user who is NOT the one you are looking for. 
Change this:

```
public boolean removePatron(int libraryCardNumber) throws PatronException{
    boolean patronRemoved = false;
    int keyToRemove = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() != libraryCardNumber) {
            throw new PatronException("This record does not exist");

        }
        keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
    }
    patrons.remove(keyToRemove);
    patronRemoved = true;
    return patronRemoved;
}
```

to this:

```
public boolean removePatron(int libraryCardNumber) {
    boolean patronRemoved = false;
    int keyToRemove = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet()) 
    {
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() == libraryCardNumber) 
        {
            keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        patrons.remove(keyToRemove);
    }
    return patronRemoved;
}
```

or more concisely as AmitD showed

Comment: went with this because it conformed most to what I needed to fulfill to the project. I made a couple small changes, I'll add to those to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You get exception because of following code

```
 if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() != libraryCardNumber) {
        throw new PatronException("This record does not exist");

    }
```

Consider there are 3 records [0,1,2] in Map and you pass `libraryCardNumber` as 1. Your condition fails for the first time only. Note hashmap does not guarantee order and example in order is taken just for better understanding

```
public boolean removeDuplicateCardNumber(int libraryCardNumber) {
    for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, Patron>> i = myMap.entrySet()
            .iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry = i.next();
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() == libraryCardNumber) {
            i.remove();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Patron> entry : patrons.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() != libraryCardNumber) {
            throw new PatronException("This record does not exist");

        }
        keyToRemove = entry.getKey();
    }
```

has

```
if (entry.getValue().getCardNumber() != libraryCardNumber) {
        throw new PatronException("This record does not exist");

}
```

So if the first entry doesn't match your parameter the exception will be thrown. Which is why you are getting the custom exception thrown. Logic is flawed.

Well on a second look it may be a bit more complex than this because you haven't provided the bit of code where you add an entry. But this would be my first guess...

EDIT:

Also it seems to me that you want to check if the value exist and if ti does remove it. You don't have to loop through to achieve this.

Take a look at `containsKey` and `containsValue` methods in HashMap API. Then you can simply call the `remove` method.

Also after reading the comment you should be evaluating `if (**entry.getKey()** != libraryCardNumber)` this is much cleaner than relying on you mutable value objects field.

Answer (score 0):

That *if* statement (inside the *for* loop) will NOT be matched EXCEPT for one record. That *if* statement has to be moved beyond the *for* loop.

The statement after the *if* block also has to leave the for loop. You do no want that action being done for EVERY member of the MAP, just one member of the map.

Try the containsKey function of java.util.Map.